# How to not allow any commits in case of any build - lint errors

Tags: javascript, git, npm, build, hook

For any git repository we have git hooks under .git/hooks folder.

Added a `npm run lint` command in pre-commit git hook. 
Not able to stop the commit in case of `npm run lint` returning error

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `pre-commit` hook https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks.

Make sure it is an active (executable) client side hook.

> Exiting non-zero from this hook aborts the commit, although you can bypass it with git commit --no-verify. You can do things like check for code style (run lint or something equivalent), check for trailing whitespace (the default hook does exactly this), or check for appropriate documentation on new methods.